# How to migrate user data & settings, if the old machine is not working but I can mount the old drive on the new one?

Tags: migration

My motherboard suddenly died, but it was an old machine(running natty). So I put together a new Ubuntu system with a clean 14.04 install (same username) and mounted the old drive (with the full filesystem) as secondary device.

I could just rsync the home dir from the old drive to the new.

Should I skip hidden files and dirs?
Or reinstall software and then paste config data (hidden files and folders) from the old drive on top of the clean installs?

Comment: I would copy into (all hidden files and directories) then reinstall the apps associated with the files.

Comment: @eyoung100 when doing clean install of applications, do they recognize and process pre-existing config files if they find them in the right place?

Comment: Yes, be aware I flagged your MySQL question as a duplicate of this one.  You may want to update this one....

Comment: @eyoung100 i posted both questions together initially, and was told to split and repost

Comment: Just add an HR and Add an update that this also includes MySQL and other Apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply copy the files from your home directory. You must include hidden files: most configuration files are hidden files or in hidden directories.

Software installation at the system level is independent from user configuration files. You can do software installation and user configuration restoration in either order.

Make sure to preserve file permissions. You can use

```
cp -a /media/usb1/home/newbie/ ~/
```

or

```
rsync -a /media/usb1/home/newbie/ ~/
```